# Postfix から hotmail.com アカウントへのメール送信に失敗します

Tags: postfix

Postfix から hotmail.com アカウントへメール送信するとメール送信に失敗します。
ログを確認したところ以下のログが残っていました。

原因として何が考えられるでしょうか？
また、どのように設定すれば解決できるでしょうか？
アドバイスをよろしくお願いします。

```
May 10 20:40:18 localhost postfix/pickup[28927]: E8C323940359: uid=48 from=<info@example.com>
May 10 20:40:18 localhost postfix/cleanup[30001]: E8C323940359: message-id=<2d98a30e3cdff56dc2863f001360b6e8@aaaa.example.com>?
May 10 20:40:19 localhost postfix/qmgr[23865]: E8C323940359: from=<info@example.com>, size=1140, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 10 20:40:49 localhost postfix/smtp[30003]: connect to mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.92.152]:25: Connection timed out
May 10 20:40:49 localhost postfix/smtp[30003]: E8C323940359: to=<aaa@hotmail.com>, relay=mx3.hotmail.com[207.46.8.199]:25, delay=31, delays=0.15/0.01/30/0.14, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mx3.hotmail.com[207.46.8.199] said: 554 Transaction failed (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
May 10 20:40:49 localhost postfix/smtp[30003]: E8C323940359: lost connection with mx3.hotmail.com[207.46.8.199] while sending RCPT TO
May 10 20:40:49 localhost postfix/cleanup[30001]: A2E39394035C: message-id=<20160512144949.A2E39394035C@example.com>
May 10 20:40:49 localhost postfix/bounce[30012]: E8C323940359: sender non-delivery notification: A2E39394035C
May 10 20:40:49 localhost postfix/qmgr[23865]: A2E39394035C: from=<>, size=2973, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 10 20:40:49 localhost postfix/qmgr[23865]: E8C323940359: removed
M
```

Comment: hotmail.com 以外へは送信できている、ということでしょうか。

Comment: hotmil.com以外は送信できています。試しに、他のhotmil.comアカウントに送信してみたところ、正常に送信されました。もしかしたら送信できなかったのは、一時的な現象だったのかもしれません。

Comment: @sinsin サーバが落ちてたということ？同じコマンドでもう一度送って、今も駄目なんです？

Comment: メール送信に失敗したメールアドレスはお客様のアドレスなので、もう一度送ることはできません。私のhotmail.comアカウントだと問題なく送信できました。

Answer (score 1):

現状を読み解く
１．「mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.92.152]:25」への接続が出来なかった
※`Connection timed out`とあり、接続待機に時間がかかっている。

２．`TO`からの送信が`554 Transaction failed`となっており処理に失敗
※`in reply to MAIL FROM command`とあり、FROMからの応答が無いため失敗している

３．「mx3.hotmail.com[207.46.8.199]」への送信のための接続が失われた。
「lost connection with mx3.hotmail.com[207.46.8.199] while sending RCPT TO」
※おそらくエラーのため接続を切断したと思われる

---

可能性の話
１．メールのアカウントの認証失敗で接続拒否(FROM側が怪しい？)
２．添付ファイルが受信サーバで受け付けていない
３．受信先のサーバが落ちている
４．メール送信時に正常にリレー出来ていない(`main.cf`の設定とか怪しいかも)
５．サーバが外への接続を拒否している

送受信で同じドメインなので、FROMが接続できなかったらTOも接続できない気はしますが……
片方のみっぽいのでアカウントの認証失敗の可能性が高そう……

Comment: 現状の確認、可能性の話、勉強になります。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 接続ができていないので、1, 2 の可能性はありませんね。リレーしようとはしているし、4 もない。

Comment: mx1.hotmail.com への接続は失敗してますが mx3.hotmail.com への接続はできてますよ。

Comment: @fumiyas `relay`は確かに走っているので接続の問題が高そうですね。

Comment: @tmtms そう書いたつもりでした…ただ、mx3へ接続は出来ていましたが、mx1のほうにつながらなかったから接続を切断していますよね？

Comment: 自分のコメントは fumiyas さんの「接続ができていない」に対するコメントでした。紛らわしくてすいません。